# Can't redirect to another page at the end of the PHP script

Tags: php, url, header

Bot of these lines:

```
echo '<br/><br/>'.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."?page=".$pager->GetVariableC."&threadID=".$threadID;
header("Location:".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."?page=".$pager->GetVariableC."&threadID=".$threadID);
```

Give me this:

> /PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php?page=2&threadID=6
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Thread\comments.php:42) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Thread\thread.php on line 348

How do I redirect at the end of the script?

Comment: Did you check what is on line 42 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Thread\comments.php ?

Comment: Comment echo statement, it's not allowed to print anything before headers are sent.

Comment: yeah, I could, but I do this at the end of the script.. There are a few sql statments that need to be finish before the redirection should take place

Comment: @SeRPRo even without checking what's on that line, there is an echo statement right before the `header()` line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent, Why its happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827314/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-why-its-happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect after you've sent output to the client's browser using PHP's `header()`.

What you can do is use a `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.destination.com/">
```

Where `2` is the time before the redirect in seconds, and the `url` is the destination. You can find more information about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) (you should read the [drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks) section).

Comment: nice method.. but it is not quite what I want..cause as you can see I need to attack variables to the url and the header needs to be executed at the end of teh script

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd You still can `echo` the destination `url` using PHP. The other possible solution is to not output **anything** before the `header()` function call, since it wouldn't make much sense to `echo` anything that won't be read by the users because of the redirection.

Comment: that is true.. But the script does involve echoing.. I see your point.. I conditionally use header.. something the user reads the comments on other times I want the redirection to happen

Answer (score 3):

When this error happens, you have already sent something to the browser, by using echo or by having a couple of new lines after the closing php tag. Be sure not to have any new lines or echoing something before redirecting.

Comment: In a PHP script that you do some actions and redirect at the end, there's no point in outputting something (echo). So you must ensure that you don't echo something before redirecting. Check the logic of the script, if you miss something.

Comment: I will not use that redirect.. too bad there is no way, In asp.net there is Server.Redirect or Response.Redirect ... :(

Comment: You can always use PHP's output buffering (http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), or use a simple variable to concatenate all output and in case the redirect is not about to happen, echo this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect after you've already sent any data to the browser, in this case the first line is doing so. Why are you trying to print something that you are never going to see (The browser would be immediately redirected)?

Either remove the outputting lines above the redirect if possible, or look into using output buffers if you can't modify the surrounding code.

Comment: I want to execute an insert statement, after it is executed, I want the user to be redirected to another page

Comment: Then why not just insert then redirect? Providing you don't output anything then that would work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want output and a redirection then you need to use a javascript redirection. http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php
What you're doing here is called an HTTP redirection (an HTTP 302), which is one of the HTTP headers sent to the browser as a response.
This error message is due to the fact that you echo'd content which has the effect of sending out all the buffered HTTP headers then tried to set a header (but it was already sent). To get a much better view of this I recommend all web developers install firebug and monitor the "Network" tab, you'll really get a better grasp on headers and their meanings.

Cheers

Comment: I see what you mean, but I dont want to use javascript..too bad I cant use this function